# zoom in/out graph using AWT on Applet

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtutilities

I am newbie to the java....working on a piece of applet code...............as I am still going through the OOPs concepts and java understanding and need to develop below mentioned functionality.
The piece of code I have works like this :
First it reads all parameters from HTML tags and stores in global variables. Then it sends query to CGI to read graph data. Then it converts data for plotting and draws graph. There is a option for user to select 1-24 hours. Based on the selection graph will be plotted by plotting only selected data. Every 30 sec it sends query to CGI for collecting data.

The code uses following library and uses java 1.5 environment and i cannot change it due to embeded requirements :

I need to enchance it by implementing zoom in zoom out feature with x-y axis granuality changing with zoom in .
My worry is how to do that?I know its Frustrating question ...but i am here to get suggestion from the java experts so that I can quickly learn and implement this stuff.

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

/******************************************************************************
*
* Class - Graph
*
*       This is the entry point.
*   This class extends Applet class and implements Runnable.
*
*****************************************************************************/

public class GraphPerf extends Applet implements Runnable,ItemListener,MouseMotionListener

{
//Global variables
int MAX_DATA_X  ;
int    SIZE_X= 480;
int    SIZE_Y= 250;
int    SIZE_Y1= 240;
int MIN_ERROR = -1;
int MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT = 1001;
int MAX_ERROR_COUNT = 101;
int SIZE_Y_EXTENDED_BOTTOM = 20;
int MAX_DISP_PARMS = 16;
int MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY = 96;
int MAX_DISP_PARMS_STD = 7;
int refreshTime;
String  serverAddress,hostAddr;
Color   plotColor1,plotColor8;

float graphData[][];
float graph_data_rf_east,graph_data_rf_west;

int xOffset = 50;
int yOffset = 40;

int Y1_MAX_VALUE = 100;
int Y2_MAX_VALUE = 3;

float RANGE2;

Thread  graphThread;
Image   Buffer;
Graphics plot;

Choice  timeChoice, modeChoice, seloptChoice;
int     duration=1, viewMode=1, line_type = 0,viewOpt = 1;

Label valueLabel1, valueLabel2,valueLabel3,valueLabel4,valueLabel5;
boolean GraphBottomExtendFlag=true;


/******************************************************************************
*
* method - init
*
*       This is the method called first after applet loaded in to browser.
*   This function reads configurable parameters from HTML tag and updates
*   global variables.
*****************************************************************************/

public void init()
{

MAX_DATA_X = 672;//Integer.parseInt(getParameter("max_data_x"));
//refreshTime       = 30;//Integer.parseInt(getParameter("refresh_sec"));
/*URL url = getDocumentBase();
String host = url.getHost();
try
{
    InetAddress addr =  InetAddress.getByName(host);
    hostAddr=addr.getHostAddress();
}catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
 */
//serverAddress     = new String ( getParameter("access_str")+ hostAddr + getParameter("data_server"));
graphData       = new float[MAX_DISP_PARMS][MAX_DATA_X+1];
/*initialize the array with -1 not with 0(0 also valid for graph data)  */
int i =0,j = 0;
for( j=0; j<MAX_DISP_PARMS; j++)
{
    for( i=0; i<MAX_DATA_X+1; i++)
    {
        graphData[j][i] = -1;
    }
}
graph_data_rf_east = -1;
graph_data_rf_west = -1;

plotColor1      = Color.orange;
plotColor2      = Color.black;
plotColor8      = Color.red;
plotColor9      = Color.green;

setBackground(Color.white);
setLayout(null);

timeChoice   = new Choice();
timeChoice.add("1");
timeChoice.add("2");
timeChoice.add("3");
timeChoice.add("4");
timeChoice.add("5");
timeChoice.add("6");
timeChoice.add("7");
add(timeChoice);

timeChoice.setBounds(190,340,40,23);
timeChoice.addItemListener(this);

Label timeLabel1 = new Label("View graph for last");
Label timeLabel2 = new Label("day(s)");
add(timeLabel1);
timeLabel1.setBounds(xOffset+30,340,160,23);

add(timeLabel2);
timeLabel2.setBounds(240,340,50,23);

valueLabel1 = new Label();
add(valueLabel1);
valueLabel1.setBounds(300,340,50,23);
valueLabel2 = new Label();
add(valueLabel2);
valueLabel2.setBounds(370,340,70,23);
valueLabel3 = new Label();
add(valueLabel3);
valueLabel3.setBounds(440,340,70,23);
valueLabel4 = new Label();
add(valueLabel4);
valueLabel4.setBounds(500,340,70,23);
valueLabel5 = new Label();
add(valueLabel5);
valueLabel5.setBounds(370,370,80,25);
modeChoice = new Choice();
modeChoice.add("East");
modeChoice.add("West");
/* Display this only for Protected and East-West Mode */
if(2/*Integer.parseInt(getParameter("mode"))*/ == 2)
{
    add(modeChoice);
}
else
{
    viewOpt = 1;
}
modeChoice.setBounds(xOffset+SIZE_X-55, 0, 60, 25);
modeChoice.addItemListener(this);
addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

public void start()
{
graphThread = new Thread(this);
graphThread.start();
}

public void stop()
{
graphThread = null;
}

/******************************************************************************
*
*   This method will be called after starting the thread. This is a
*   infinite loop which will call query method for every 30 sec to read data
*   from CGI. Then it plots graph by calling plotGraph method
*   the thread.
*****************************************************************************/

public void run()
{
/*while (false)
{
    try
    {//getData(serverAddress);
        int sizeY = SIZE_Y;
        if(GraphBottomExtendFlag)
        {
            sizeY += SIZE_Y_EXTENDED_BOTTOM;
        }
        repaint(xOffset+1,yOffset+1,SIZE_X-1,sizeY-1);
        //graphThread.sleep(refreshTime*1000);
    }catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
}*/
}

/******************************************************************************
*
* method - paint
*
*       This method displays the graph plotted by plotGraph method
*   in the screen. Then it draws axis for the graph
*
*****************************************************************************/

public void paint(Graphics g1)
{
int sizeY = SIZE_Y;
/*If  Graph Bottom is to be Etended
 *soo that zero is displayed properly
 */
if(GraphBottomExtendFlag)
{
    sizeY += SIZE_Y_EXTENDED_BOTTOM;
}

if( duration <= 5 )
{
    Buffer = createImage(SIZE_X, sizeY);
    plot = Buffer.getGraphics();
    plotGraph(plot);
    g1.drawImage (Buffer,xOffset,yOffset,this);
}
else
{
    Buffer = createImage(MAX_DATA_X*duration/7,sizeY);
    plot = Buffer.getGraphics();
    plotGraph(plot);
    g1.drawImage (Buffer,xOffset,yOffset,SIZE_X,sizeY,this);
}

g1.setColor(Color.black);

g1.drawRect(70,150,270,80);
/*Dram Graph boarder */
g1.drawRect(xOffset,yOffset,SIZE_X,sizeY);
g1.drawRect(xOffset-1,yOffset-1,SIZE_X+2,sizeY+2);

      /*Plot X axis*/
int max_x_marks = 8;
int temp = 1,cnt_graph = 0;
int float_temp,float_temp2;

/*max 8 plots on x axis*/
for(int x=max_x_marks; x>0; x--)
{

    float_temp = (int)((MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY*duration)/max_x_marks)*((max_x_marks+1)-x);
    float_temp2 = SIZE_X-(60*cnt_graph);

    g1.drawString(String.valueOf(float_temp),(float_temp2-20) ,SIZE_Y+yOffset+35);
    cnt_graph++;
}

/*Plot Y1 AXIS*/
temp = Y1_MAX_VALUE;
for(int x = 0; x <= SIZE_Y; x+= 25)
{
    g1.drawString(String.valueOf(temp), 25, x + yOffset+10);
    temp -= (Y1_MAX_VALUE - 0)/10;
}
temp = 1000;
 /*Plot Y2 AXIS*/
int index_log = 1;
for(int x = 0; x <= SIZE_Y1; x+= 80)
{
    if(x== 240)
    index_log--;
    if(temp>=1)
    {
        g1.drawString(String.valueOf(temp), 550, x+yOffset+8-index_log);
        g1.drawLine(530,x+yOffset+5-index_log, 540, x+yOffset+5-index_log);
    }
    temp = temp/10;
}
Font thisFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14);
g1.setFont(thisFont);
g1.drawString("Y2", 550, 160);
g1.drawString("Y1",5, 160);

}
/******************************************************************************
 *
 * method - plotGraph
 *
 *      Depending on the mode, "East", "West" or "Combined", it plots
 *  single or two graphs in the same applet.
 *
 *  Inputs :
 *          g - Graphics object
 *****************************************************************************/

public void plotGraph(Graphics g)
{
g.setColor(new Color(255,255,220));

/*If  Error-Sec-Count Graph
 *Then extend the lower portion
 *soo that zero is displayed properly
 */
if(GraphBottomExtendFlag)
{
    g.fillRect(0,0,MAX_DATA_X,SIZE_Y + SIZE_Y_EXTENDED_BOTTOM);
}
else
{
    g.fillRect(0,0,MAX_DATA_X,SIZE_Y);
}


switch(viewMode)
{
    case 1 :
        plot1(g);
        plot_timeelapsed_east(g);
        break;

    case 2 :
        plot8(g);
        plot_timeelapsed_west(g);
        break;
}
}
/******************************************************************************
 *
 * method - plot1
 *
 *      This method uses graphData[0][] global variable and plots series of lines
 *  in the applet
 *
 *  Inputs :
 *          g - Graphics object
 *****************************************************************************/

 void plot1(Graphics g)
 {
int end = MAX_DATA_X;
int localPlotBuffer[];

localPlotBuffer = new int[2];

g.setColor(plotColor1);
if(duration > 5)
{
    for(int x=(duration*MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY); x > 0 ; x--)
    {
        /*if data is valid data then plot else ignore*/
        if((graphData[0][end]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[0][end-1]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT)&&(graphData[0][end-1]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[0][end]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT))
        {
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[0][end] == 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[0][end]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[0][end])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[0][end-1] == 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[0][end-1]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[0][end-1])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            g.drawLine(x-1,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5), x-2,(localPlotBuffer[1]+5));
            g.drawLine(x,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5), x-1,(localPlotBuffer[1]+5));
        }
        end--;
    }
}
else
{
    float temp = SIZE_X;
    for(int x=(duration*MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY) ; x > 0 ; x--)
    {
        float LocalTemp1 = temp;
        float LocalTemp2 = (int)(temp-(double)5/(double)duration);
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        if(duration == 1)
        {
            if(LocalTemp1>(SIZE_X-3))
            LocalTemp1 = SIZE_X;
            if(LocalTemp2>(SIZE_X-3))
            LocalTemp2 = SIZE_X;
        }
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        else if(duration == 2)
        {
            if(LocalTemp1>(SIZE_X-2))
            LocalTemp1 = SIZE_X;
            if(LocalTemp2>(SIZE_X-2))
            LocalTemp2 = SIZE_X;
        }
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        else if(duration == 3)
        {
            if(LocalTemp1>(SIZE_X-1))
            LocalTemp1 = SIZE_X;
            if(LocalTemp2>(SIZE_X-1))
            LocalTemp2 = SIZE_X;
        }
        /*if data is valid data then plot else ignore*/
        if((graphData[0][end]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[0][end-1]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT)&&(graphData[0][end-1]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[0][end]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT))
        {
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[0][end] == 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[0][end]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[0][end])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[0][end-1] == 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[0][end-1]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[0][end-1])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            g.drawLine((int)LocalTemp1,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5), (int)LocalTemp2,(localPlotBuffer[1]+5));
        }
        temp-=(double)5/(double)duration;
        end--;
    }
}
}

/******************************************************************************
*
* method - plot8
*
*       This method uses graphData[7][] global variable and plots series of lines
*   in the applet
*
*   Inputs :
*           g - Graphics object
*****************************************************************************/

void plot8(Graphics g)
{
int end = MAX_DATA_X;
int localPlotBuffer[];
localPlotBuffer = new int[2];

g.setColor(plotColor1);

if(duration > 5)
{
    for(int x=(duration*MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY); x > 0 ;x-- )
    {
        /*if data is valid data then plot else ignore*/
        if((graphData[8][end]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[8][end-1]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT)&&(graphData[8][end-1]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[8][end]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT))
        {
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[8][end] == 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[8][end]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[8][end])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[8][end-1]== 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[8][end-1]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[8][end-1])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            g.drawLine(x-1,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5), x-2,(localPlotBuffer[1]+5));
            g.drawLine(x,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5), x-1,(localPlotBuffer[1]+5));
        }
        end--;
    }
}
else
{
    float temp = SIZE_X;
    for(int x=(duration*MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY) ; x > 0 ; x--)
    {
        float LocalTemp1 = temp;
        float LocalTemp2 = (int)(temp-(double)5/(double)duration);
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        if(duration == 1)
        {
            if(LocalTemp1>(SIZE_X-3))
            LocalTemp1 = SIZE_X;
            if(LocalTemp2>(SIZE_X-3))
            LocalTemp2 = SIZE_X;
        }
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        else if(duration == 2)
        {
            if(LocalTemp1>(SIZE_X-2))
            LocalTemp1 = SIZE_X;
            if(LocalTemp2>(SIZE_X-2))
            LocalTemp2 = SIZE_X;
        }
        /*Normalise the pixcel positions */
        else if(duration == 3)
        {
            if(LocalTemp1>(SIZE_X-1))
            LocalTemp1 = SIZE_X;
            if(LocalTemp2>(SIZE_X-1))
            LocalTemp2 = SIZE_X;
        }
        /*if data is valid data then plot else ignore*/
        if((graphData[8][end]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[8][end-1]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT)&&(graphData[8][end-1]>MIN_ERROR)&&(graphData[8][end]<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT))
        {
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[8][end] == 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[8][end]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[8][end])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            /*if data present is 0, log10(0) is not define so then plot this graph in normal scale */
            if(graphData[8][end-1]== 0)
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y )*(float)(1 - (float)graphData[8][end-1]/(float)Y1_MAX_VALUE)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                localPlotBuffer[1] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graphData[8][end-1])/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
            }
            g.drawLine((int)LocalTemp1,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5), (int)LocalTemp2,(localPlotBuffer[1]+5));
        }
        temp-=(double)5/(double)duration;
        end--;
    }
}
}

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * method - plot_timeelapsed_east
 *
 *      This method uses graph_data_rf_east global variable and plots series of lines
 *  in the applet
*****************************************************************************/

void plot_timeelapsed_east(Graphics g)
{
int end = MAX_DATA_X;
int localPlotBuffer[];
int x= 0;

localPlotBuffer = new int[2];
x= (duration*MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY);
g.setColor(plotColor9);
/*if data is valid data then plot else ignore*/
if((graph_data_rf_east>0)&&(graph_data_rf_east<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT))
{
    localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graph_data_rf_east)/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
    if(duration>5)
    g.drawLine(x-1,SIZE_Y+5, x-2,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5));
    else
    g.drawLine(SIZE_X,SIZE_Y+5, 474+duration,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5));
}
  }/*End for plot_timeelapsed_east() */

 /******************************************************************************
 *
 * method - plot_timeelapsed_west
 *
 *      This method uses graph_data_rf_east global variable and plots series of lines
 *  in the applet
 *****************************************************************************/

void plot_timeelapsed_west(Graphics g)
{
int end = MAX_DATA_X;
int localPlotBuffer[];
int x= 0;

localPlotBuffer = new int[2];
x= (duration*MAX_NUM_INTERVELL_PER_DAY);

g.setColor(plotColor9);
/*if data is valid data then plot else ignore*/
if((graph_data_rf_east>MIN_ERROR)&&(graph_data_rf_east<MAX_LOG10_ERROR_COUNT))
{
    localPlotBuffer[0] = (int)((float)(SIZE_Y1 )*(float)(1 - (float)Math.log10(graph_data_rf_west)/(float)Y2_MAX_VALUE));
    if(duration>5)
    g.drawLine(x-1,SIZE_Y+5, x-2,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5));
    else
    g.drawLine(SIZE_X,SIZE_Y+5, 474+duration,(localPlotBuffer[0]+5));
}
}

/******************************************************************************
*
* method - getData
*
*       This method sends query to CGI to collect data. Then it converts the
*   data for applet area then updates global variable.
*
*   Inputs :
*           serverAddress - server CGI path
*****************************************************************************/

public void getData(String serverAddress)
{

URL addr;
BufferedReader in;
String inputLine;
int count = 0;
int i=0,j = 0;
try
{
    addr = new URL(serverAddress);
    URLConnection connection = addr.openConnection();
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(addr.openStream()));
    /*Read data for first link */
    for( j=0; j<MAX_DISP_PARMS_STD; j++)
    {
        for( i=0; i<MAX_DATA_X+1; i++)
        {
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            graphData[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
        }
    }
    for( i=0; i<MAX_DATA_X; i++)
    {
        inputLine = in.readLine();
        graphData[7][i] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
        if(graphData[7][i] == 1)
        graphData[7][i] = 10;
    }
    inputLine = in.readLine();
    graph_data_rf_east = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
    /*Reading data for second link */
    if(Integer.parseInt(getParameter("mode")) == 2)
    {
        for( j=8; j<15; j++)
        {
            for( i=0; i<MAX_DATA_X+1; i++)
            {
                inputLine = in.readLine();
                graphData[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
            }

        }
        for( i=0; i<MAX_DATA_X; i++)
        {
            inputLine = in.readLine();
            graphData[15][i] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
            if(graphData[15][i] == 1)
            graphData[15][i] = 10;
        }
        inputLine = in.readLine();
        graph_data_rf_west = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
}catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Server Data Read Error:"+e); }
}

/******************************************************************************
 *
 * method - itemStateChanged
 *
 *      This method will be called whenever event occured on this choice.
 *  it read the current status and changes scale accordingly.
 * *****************************************************************************/

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt)
{
if( evt.getSource() == timeChoice )
    duration = Integer.parseInt(timeChoice.getSelectedItem());
else
    viewMode = modeChoice.getSelectedIndex()+1;
repaint();
}
/******************************************************************************
 *
 * method - mouseMoved
 *
 *      This method will be called whenever mouse cursor is moved over the
 *  applet. Depending on the cursor position, it will display Actual
 *  X and Y values of the graph.
 *****************************************************************************/

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt)
{
    int x = evt.getX()-xOffset;
    int y = evt.getY()-yOffset-5;

    int a = evt.getX();
    int b = evt.getY();

    int duration = Integer.parseInt(timeChoice.getSelectedItem());
    if( (x>=0) && (x<=SIZE_X) && (y>=0) && (y<=SIZE_Y) )
    {
        valueLabel1.setText("X ");
        valueLabel2.setText("Y1 ");
        valueLabel3.setText("Y2 ");
        try
        {
            int x_max_value = ((SIZE_X*duration)/5);
            int x1  = (int)((float)((float)((float)(SIZE_X*duration))/5)  * ((float)((float)(SIZE_X - x))/((float)SIZE_X)));
            /*For Durations less than 16 scale starts with 1*/
            int y1  = (int)((float)Y1_MAX_VALUE  * (((float)SIZE_Y - (float)y)/((float)SIZE_Y)));
            int y2 = (int) Math.pow(10,((float)(3 * ((float)(1 - (float)y/((float)SIZE_Y1))))));
            valueLabel1.setText("X="+x1);
            valueLabel2.setText("X pix="+a);
            valueLabel3.setText("Y="+y1);
            valueLabel4.setText("Y pix="+b);
            valueLabel5.setText("Y2="+y2);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Mouse Moved Error" + e);}
    }
    else
    {
        valueLabel1.setText(" ");
        valueLabel2.setText(" ");
        valueLabel3.setText(" ");

    }
}
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JCC kit for my target platform and it's less than 100kb library. You need to understand  the library and after that you can play without worrying about size. :)

Good library to use in embedded systems whether size is always the issue. it has inbuilt function o transform coordinates into screen coordinates and vice-verse.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here are two:

1. You can simply scale the values: Multiply every coordinate with the zoom factor.
2. Use Java2D and `AffineTransform`:

   ```
   AffineTransform transformer = new AffineTransform();
   transformer.scale(zoom, zoom);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
   g2d.setTransform(transformer);
   // draw to g2d.
   ```

**[EDIT]** If you want to do everything yourself, see this page for a refresh of basic linear algebra: [2D Transformations](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm)

Don't mind the 3D example at the top; the rest of the page is about 2D.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aaron...........Whether AffineTransform can be used with mouse scroll event so that its zoom accordingly whereever mouse focus is in graph?.Here i am bothered about granuality of x-y axis when zoom in happens so that graph ploted gives me more accurate values on x-y axis.....and also I have two y axis with different max and min values.

Comment: You can use `AffineTransform` for that. This blog post should help: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19387.html As for accurate: First convert the model values (= real values) to screen coordinates, convert those to floating point, scale, render the result.

Comment: Thanks blog seems to have pretty good inputs.If you have noticed In my question i have mentioned that i can't use new library i.e swing etc...i m restricted to AWT......I know its gonna be complicated.....I am working on it and learning.....will trouble you more in this sure.

Comment: `Graphics2D` is in `java.awt`

Comment: "First convert the model values (= real values) to screen coordinates, convert those to floating point, scale, render the result".................@Aaron Please can you elaborate with respect to implementation in java. Is there any tutorial on adding graphs and deploying it as applet so that i can refer.

Comment: This is basic linear algebra :-/ Didn't you have math at school?

Comment: Is there any function that transforms device points to the application coordinate space points apart from inverseTransform function used by AffineTransform.

Comment: No, that's what the inverse matrix is for.

Comment: Hi Aaron ......I tried to add zoom in/out functionality in  following code but my efforts are going in useless........Please go through and can u tell wat you can do with this inorder to implement zoom.......

Comment: You can run above code its compilable and executing.................<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <CENTER><H2> RF Link Performance Graph </H2>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <APPLET ALIGN="CENTER"CODE="GraphPerf.class" WIDTH="580" HEIGHT="370"></APPLET>
 <H4> X (Horizontal) Axis - Interval (15 Min) Count  <br> Y1 (Vertical)   Axis - ESR, SESR, BBER, SUSPECT <br>Y2 (Vertical)   Axis - ES, SES, BBE, UAS, TIME-ELAPSED Log<sub>10</sub> Count</H4>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>

Comment: Take a piece of paper, draw the two views (real world and screen) onto it, add coordinates and then apply your math skills to figure out how to convert one coordinate into the other. Use the formulas from the link I've sent you.

Comment: I tried that...but Have you executed the code i have sent? i need to fix according to the code I have sent...in the above code x-y axis origin is not normal one,it starts from bottom right corner. Its first creats a image which has some line and then draws rectangle and then it just prints the scale value along the x and y axis of rectangle.....Please dont go into basics of graph implementation but see the code which need to be fix.

Comment: No, I don't have time for that. Reduce the code to a few JUnit test which convert coordinates from one system to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help.i am using jfree charts now.